# JetpackCompose @PreviewParameter causes preview to disappear

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been exploring Jetpack Compose lately and discovered this very weird scenario where my `@Preview` is not showing and Android Studio is literally showing blank empty. No warnings or errors are shown.

This happens when I add `@PreviewParameter` to my composable function parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stupid solution was… It turns out that I had my PreviewParameterProvider declared in `private` and turning it to `public` or simply removing the visibility modifier fixed it.

```
class MyProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<MyClass> {
    ...
}
```

This wasn't even documented.

I hope Google will make it clear in the documentation or at least give an error in Android Studio so developers won't encounter this frustrating and time-wasting scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Google should fix this, it doesn't even show an error...
It also works using `internal` modifier.

Comment: just to add to this, `PreviewParameterProvider` also can't be declared as an object or you'll get the same issues.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this. I also had to make sure my @Composable functions themselves were public, not private.

Answer (score 5):

I had another issue causing the same behaviour.

### blank screen

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyComposablePreview(
    @PreviewParameter(MyComposableStateProvider::class) state: MyComposableState
) = MyComposable(state)
```

### works

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyComposablePreview(
    @PreviewParameter(MyComposableStateProvider::class) state: MyComposableState
) {
  MyComposable(state)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for finding this! It would be interesting to know why this is happening. I expect something related to [the compose compiler plugin](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd); is this a bug or not. :/

Answer (score 3):

I can also add that your implementation of PreviewParameterProvider should not be inner class and should not be inside other class. So

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

  class MyProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<MyComposableStateProvider> {
    ...
  }

  @Preview
  @Composable
  fun MyComposablePreview(
    @PreviewParameter(MyProvider::class) state: MyComposableState
  ) {
    MyComposable(state)
  }
}
```

**won't work either.** extract providers to separate files.